# Pyramid-JSONP-Third Party Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, pyramid

I am using pyramid to serve my app and have started learning jquery.I am trying to make a social widget for my app.

Domain 1(localhost:**8088**) is making  a request to anotherhost Domain2(10.20.12.135:8080/ which is actually localhost:8080) i.e both are running on same system

Here is the code:
Domain1

```
try{
    $.getJSON( "http://10.20.12.135:8080/ajax?name=stackoverflow", function( data ) {
    alert(data)
    }); } 
catch(err) {  
  alert("Ops, there was an error!\n\n" + err); 
}
```

Domain2:[Reference](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/narr/renderers.html)

```
@view_config(route_name='ajax',renderer='json')
def get_cookie(request):
    name=request.get('name','world')
    return {'name':name,'id':343434,'secret':'3434sfdgdfg'}
```

When Domain1 is run firebug shows that the get request has return nothing and is in red.And none of the alert is  shown.

Debugging jquery shows 'JSON.parse: unexpected end of data Line 4 '

However making a get request from browser to 10.20.12.135:8080/ajax?name=stackoverflow returns **{'name':'stackoverflow','id':343434,'secret':'3434sfdgdfg'}**

Instead of $.getJSON I tried $.ajax but got the same result(i.e nothing)

2.While making jsonp request from domain1 to domain2, will the browser send the domain2 cookie as headers.

Comment: Cookies are never cross-domain, although they can work across sub-domains if specified.

Comment: The Domain 2 cookie information is being sent to Domain2 only.How is it cross domain?

Comment: You said, "while making jsonp request from domain1 to domain2." That's cross-domain.